# Jest stub doesn't change state of fake repository

Tags: typescript, jestjs, stub

I am trying to stub my repository.

My DB is faked by an array of string.

I wish that this array get populated with one new entry when my code call `repository.saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks`, but nothing seems to happen.

Be more clear with this code.

```
describe('saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks', () => {
    it('should save given job offer into bookmarks', async () => {
      let fakeAllBookmarks = ['Sales associate', 'Crew member', 'Barista']
      const jobOfferToBeSaved = { id: 2, job: 'Captain' }

      repository.saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks = jest.fn(jobOfferId => {
        console.log(jobOfferId)
        if (jobOfferId === jobOfferToBeSaved.id)
          fakeAllBookmarks.push(jobOfferToBeSaved.job)
        return Promise.resolve(2)
      })

      console.log(fakeAllBookmarks)
      repository.getAllBookmarkedJobOffers = jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(fakeAllBookmarks)
      })

      const candidateId = 614
      const jobOfferId = 2
      const retrievedBookmarks = await service.getAllBookmarkedJobOffers(
        candidateId
      )
      console.log(retrievedBookmarks)
      expect(retrievedBookmarks).toStrictEqual([
        'Sales associate',
        'Crew member',
        'Barista',
        'Captain',
      ])
      expect(repository.saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        candidateId,
        jobOfferId
      )
    })
  })
```

Here is the console test result :

```
● BookmarksService › saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks › should save given job offer into bookmarks

    expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 0

      Array [
        "Sales associate",
        "Crew member",
        "Barista",
    -   "Captain",
      ]

      65 |       )
      66 |       console.log(retrievedBookmarks)
    > 67 |       expect(retrievedBookmarks).toStrictEqual([
         |                                  ^
      68 |         'Sales associate',
      69 |         'Crew member',
      70 |         'Barista',

      at Object.<anonymous> (bookmarks/bookmarks.service.spec.ts:67:34)

  console.log
    [ 'Sales associate', 'Crew member', 'Barista' ]

      at Object.<anonymous> (bookmarks/bookmarks.service.spec.ts:56:15)

  console.log
    [ 'Sales associate', 'Crew member', 'Barista' ]

      at Object.<anonymous> (bookmarks/bookmarks.service.spec.ts:66:15)
```

The `console.log()` inside the stub doesn't seem to be triggered as well.

Comment: saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks isn't called in this test, so it doesn't change anything. You could move `expect(repository.saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks)` above equality assertion to make it clear. It's unclear what's the purpose of this test. You call your own getAllBookmarkedJobOffers mock.

Comment: "You call your own getAllBookmarkedJobOffers mock"

That was the problem! Thanks for proofreading my code.

I had the intent to assert the `service.saveJobOfferIntoBookmarks()` that should add the job offer into the bookmarks. And it solve the issue.